# Assign difference value in for loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to write a simple program to get payment in class using vb.net. I want to add payment month by month as

- if student pay 500$ for 6 month and member fee is 90$ then I want to add it to database like this:

Sample data:

```
Jan 90
Feb 90
mar 90
APR 90
may 90
jun 50
```

and (- 40$) extend to next month

I want to add it using for loop. I am working with vb.net and MS Access database. Currently I am get month diff from two date and add it to for loop and send the database unique amount

```
  Dim date1 As Date = DateTime.Parse(frodate.Text)
        Dim date2 As Date = DateTime.Parse(todate.Text)
        Dim dif As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Month, date1, date2)
        totmonth.Text = dif

    Dim ix As Integer
    Dim month = Today.Month
    For ix = 0 To dif - 1
        Dim newDate As DateTime = date1.AddMonths(ix)
        Dim monthid As Integer = newDate.Month
        Dim mname = MonthName(monthid)

        objcon.myconnection.Open()


        Try
            Dim adddata As New OleDbCommand(("insert into payment(payment_id,mem_id,payment_type,payment_date,Payment_amount,payment_remark,mem_name,payment_month)" &
                                               "values('" & paymentid.Text & "'," & paymemid2.Text & ",'" & payment_type_combo.Text & "','" & paymentdate.Text & "','" & payment_amount.Text & "','" & payremark.Text & "','" & memname.Text & "','" & mname & "')"), objcon.myconnection)
            adddata.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim addtransection As New OleDbCommand("insert into account(trans_id,trans_type,trans_date,credit,flag)" &
                                                   "values('" & paymentid.Text & "','" & payment_type_combo.Text & "','" & paymentdate.Text & "','" & payment_amount.Text & "',1)", objcon.myconnection)
            addtransection.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Payment  Sucsess")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        objcon.myconnection.Close()
```

Comment: What a nice homework! What did you try so far and where is the problem?

Comment: this is currently i am doing  ''

Comment: Unforunately, we are not a coding service. We may help you, but don't make your homework.

Comment: payment button code is there and  if you can give a idea i can develop it from my ways thank you

Comment: First, try to use parameters in your query. Otherwise there may happen a sql-injection. You will have to use a variable with the payment of the student. I would solve the loop using `DO ... LOOP UNTIL payment < 0` and decrement the payment-variable each loop by 90.